# How can I create a Python script that checks a text file for availability on a website?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have a list of usernames and I want the script to add each username (from usernames.txt) to the end of the url (which is how it would check if the username is taken or not), what should i do?
basically i am creating a username checker
it needs to read (from the usernames.txt) then write once the operation completes (to the usernames.txt)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

myfile = open("usernames.txt", "w")

check1 = input("Enter a username: ")

r  = requests.get("http://website.com/m/" +check1)

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
with open('usernames.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    myfile.write(data)

print(soup.get_text())
```

(Manual Version - Doesn't check from usernames.txt, only checks the given username and then writes if it is taken or not - I want it to scan through usernames.txt)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

myfile = open("usernames.txt", "w")

check1 = input("Enter a token: ")

r  = requests.get("http://website.com/m/" +check1)

data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
with open('usernames.txt', 'w') as myfile:
    myfile.write(data)

print(soup.get_text())
```

This for example works manually by entering a username (called token in this example), I've had to snip the real website URL just for my privacy sake

Comment: Show us the content or at least the structure of usernames.txt, then we can help you.

Comment: @Anteino usernames.txt is formatted by each username on a new line.

Comment: you will need to read the file then looping on each username while making a `GET` request to the url with format string indicating the username, you can validate the response by response code or error of page content.

Comment: @itsalexlol in case if the username is available ? the page response with which code ? and if not ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Once the manual version checks the inputted username, it will write the status code (which is 404) to the text file.

Comment: @itsalexlol i want to know the response code for available username and taken usernames

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provided us with enough information, the code below is a simple explanation comparing `Available/Taken` usernames based on page response code. in case if you will compare to page text content so you have to change the condition below with the `string` which you will compare to

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with open('username.txt', 'r') as f:
    f = f.read().splitlines()
    for username in f:
        r = requests.get(f"http://website.com/m/{username}")
        if r.status_code != 200:
            with open('result.txt' 'a') as res:
                res.write(f"{username} Available")
        else:
            with open('taken.txt' 'a') as tak:
                tak.write(f"{username} Taken")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. This is just what I wanted, however, this isn't saving to the usernames.txt based on whether or not the account is taken or not.

Comment: so you want to save the valid result or ?

Comment: Yes, if the result of ExampleUsername is Taken/Available then write that result to usernames_available.txt

Comment: @itsalexlol so to save the output such as `username1 taken` , `username2 available`

Comment: correct, however, in separate files. For taken (usernames_taken.txt) and for available (usernames_available.txt)

Comment: @itsalexlol check my answer, and accept it if it's happy you.